# PHP filemtime returns empty

Tags: php

I have problem accessing the file modified time through php, this is the script

```
$radio_file = get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/assets/playerfiles/dist/radio_player.js';
$radio_ver = filemtime($radio_file);
```

$radio_file returns the path to the correct file, but the filemtime() function returns empty on in. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: what does `realpath($radio_file)` return ?

Comment: A URI is NOT a file path! try starting from `__DIR__`

Comment: `realpath($radio_file)` also returns empty... How should I start with `__DIR__` ?

Comment: @Gas Most probably its returning false because of wrong path or file not exist. you can check this by applying this piece of code

if (filemtime($radio_file)) { echo "return false"; }

Comment: @KhurramShaikh the files exists, since it returns the url in `$radio_file`. I inserted your check and it passes the if test, but returns the string if I negate it `if ( !filemtime($radio_file)) { echo "return false"; } `

Comment: @Gas would you like to share HTML and PHP both code here .. I will go through it .. and do mention your PHP version please

Comment: @KhurramShaikh sure, here is the latest push to the branch of our community radio's github: https://github.com/mmmnmnm/lahmacun/commit/06ea18c1729c8eb5ac1575365a900cb0a499bf12  (here is the wiki how to setup the local dev env: https://github.com/mmmnmnm/lahmacun/wiki/Local-development-environment-(install-instructions) ) Thank you if you check it!

Comment: @KhurramShaikh Sorry, forgot the php version, it is 7.2

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue when trying to provide file versioning to my CSS files in Wordpress. What worked for me was using the **get_stylesheet_directory()** function instead. As mentioned before a URI and a file path are two different things.

```
$modified_time = filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/dist/style.min.css');
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory/

> Retrieves stylesheet directory path for the active theme.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/

> Retrieves stylesheet directory URI for the active theme.